If a norm with value in an ordered field satisfies parallelogram law, must it be induced by an inner product?
Let $K$ be an ordered field, and $V$ be a vector space over $K$. We can define the concept of inner products and norms on $V$ just like on a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$. More precisely, an inner product on $V$ is a $K$-valued bilinear, symmetric, and positive definite function, and a norm on $V$ is a $K$-valued positive definite, homogeneous function that satisfies triangle inequality. (As usual, the absolute value on $K$ is defined as $|x|:=\max\{x,-x\}$.) Then it is natural to ask:

If $(V,||\cdot||)$ is a $K$-valued norm satisfying parallelogram law, meaning that
$$
\tag{1}
||x+y||^2 + ||x-y||^2=2(||x||^2+||y||^2),\quad\forall x,y\in V,
$$
must the norm be induced by an inner product, which is to say that
$$
\tag{2}
\langle x,y\rangle:=\dfrac{||x+y||^2-||x-y||^2}{4},\quad\forall x,y\in V
$$
defines a $K$-valued inner product on $V$?

The usual affirmative proof (see here) for $K=\mathbb{R}$ only proves that $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ is $\mathbb{Q}$-bilinear, then uses continuity of $\langle\alpha x,y\rangle - \alpha\langle x,y\rangle:\alpha\in K\to K$ to conclude, because $(1)$ and $(2)$ already give the Cauchy–Schwarz inequality. But for a general $K$, the continuity can only tell us that $\langle\alpha x,y\rangle = \alpha\langle x,y\rangle$ for every $\alpha$ lying in the closure of $\mathbb{Q}$, which is the "archimedean part" of $K$. So I think there is no reason to believe that $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ is $K$-bilinear.
Is it possible to prove that $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ must be $K$-bilinear, or on the contrary we can construct a $K$-valued norm satisfying parallelogram law which is not induced by an inner product? (If the latter is the case, that's perhaps why we usually don't study norms and inner products with values in fields other than $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{C}$.) Thank you for your help.

In the title you mention "order". Did you mean to include in the question that $K$ is an ordered field? If not, then for vector spaces over $Z/2Z$, the polarization identity (your equation 2) doesn't work (because division by $2$ doesn't make sense). The "Arf invariant" is essentially a riff on this idea.

@JohnHughes Yes, $K$ is an ordered field.

I don't know what you're definition of inner product or norm over an ordonned field could be (and I think that @JohnHughes was trying to answer this). Could you give us your definition of these?

@GC. They are defined just like inner products and norms are over $\mathbb{R}$.

Something that might be useful to know if you want to construct a counterexample is that every ordered field is a subfield of a formal power series field. (See the following MO question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/380713/hahn-s-theorem-on-ordered-fields.) My guess is that irregularity should come in for fairly small nontrivial extensions of $\mathbb R$, so perhaps look for a counterexample in $\mathbb R[[x]]$?

@BayleeV That's an interesting result, thanks! :)
